TypeError: tasks.map is not a function (MERN stack)
I’m working on a MERN stack “to-do list” application which performs CRUD operations. When I edit a "task" from the list, I receive Uncaught TypeError: tasks.map is not a function after I click on Save button. I’ve read similar topics here and tried multiple solutions but I still can’t fix it.
I’m sharing related code snippets and I hope someone can help me a bit. Your time and effort will be appreciated.
In my client folder, SaveTask.jsx component:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import TaskContext from '../context/TaskContext';
import TokenContext from '../context/TokenContext';
import axios from "../axios/axios";
import "../styles/saveTask.css";

function SaveTask() {
    const { tasks, dispatch } = useContext(TaskContext);
    const { userToken } = useContext(TokenContext);

    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const { editMode, taskToEdit } = tasks; // Extract editMode and taskToEdit from context

    useEffect(() => {
        // Populate form fields with task details when in editMode
        if (editMode && taskToEdit) {
            setTitle(taskToEdit.title);
            setDescription(taskToEdit.description);
        } else {
            setTitle(""); // Reset title when not editing
            setDescription(""); // Reset description when not editing
        }
    }, [editMode, taskToEdit]);

    const handleAddOrEdit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            if (editMode && taskToEdit) {
                // Update existing task
                const res = await axios.post(`/task/editTask/${taskToEdit._id}`, { title, description }, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`
                    }
                });
                console.log("Task edited:", res.data);
                // Update task in context
                dispatch({
                    type: 'EDIT_TASK',
                    _id: taskToEdit._id,
                    title: res.data.task.title,
                    description: res.data.task.description
                });

                dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_EDIT_MODE' }); // Clear edit mode after submission
            } else {
                // Add new task
                const res = await axios.post("/task/addTask", { title, description }, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`
                    }
                });
                console.log("New task added:", res.data);
                // Add new task to context
                dispatch({
                    type: "ADD_TASK",
                    _id: res.data.task._id,
                    title: res.data.task.title,
                    description: res.data.task.description,
                });
            }
            // Reset form fields
            setTitle("");
            setDescription("");

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="addContainer md:w-1/3 md:mx-auto mx-3 mt-3 flex justify-center">
            <div className='w-11/12'>
                <form onSubmit={handleAddOrEdit}>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="title"
                            id="title"
                            value={title}
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                            className='bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500'
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className='my-3'>
                        <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
                        <textarea
                            rows={5}
                            name="description"
                            id="description"
                            value={description}
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                            style={{ resize: "none" }}
                            className='bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500'
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className='flex justify-center'>
                        <button
                            type='submit'
                            className='bg-blue-700 rounded-md text-white px-5 py-1'
                        >
                            {editMode ? "Save" : "Add"}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div className="toast bg-green-600 text-white p-3 rounded-xl shadow-2xl text-center absolute bottom-4 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2" id='toast'>
                    <p>This is test</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SaveTask;

Task.jsx component:
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import "../styles/task.css";
import axios from "../axios/axios.js"
import TaskContext from '../context/TaskContext.js';
import TokenContext from '../context/TokenContext.js';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';

function Task({ task }) {
    const { _id, title, description, completed } = task;
    const { dispatch } = useContext(TaskContext);
    const { userToken } = useContext(TokenContext);

    const handleRemove = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Task ID to remove:", _id);
    
        try {
            const res = await axios.get("/task/removeTask", {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`
                },
                params: {
                    _id
                }
            });
            console.log("Task deletion response:", res.data);
            dispatch({
                type: "REMOVE_TASK",
                _id
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error removing task:", error);
            // Handle error state or display an error message to the user
        }
    }
    
    const handleMarkDone = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.post('/task/updateTaskStatus', {
                _id: task._id,
                completed: !task.completed // Toggle completion status
            }, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}` // Include JWT token in headers
                }
            }
        );
            console.log('Task completion status successfully updated:', res.data);
            dispatch({
                type: 'MARK_DONE',
                _id: task._id
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error updating task:', error);
            // Handle error state or display an error message to the user
        }
    };

    const handleEdit = () => {
        console.log('Editing task:', { task }); // Log the task details being edited
        // Dispatch an action to set the task for editing
        console.log('Dispatching SET_EDIT_MODE with task:', task);
        dispatch({
            type: 'SET_EDIT_MODE',
            payload: task // Send the entire task object for editing
        });
    };

... // Rest of the code for UI, etc.

export default Task;

AllTask.jsx component:

Also this file was returning the same TypeError: tasks.map is not a function. However it is fixed after I added Array.isArray(tasks). I can't adapt it to the current error.

import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Task from './Task';
import TaskContext from '../context/TaskContext';

function AllTask() {
    const { tasks, editMode, taskToEdit } = useContext(TaskContext);
    
    console.log('Tasks:', tasks);
    console.log('EditMode:', editMode);
    console.log('TaskToEdit:', taskToEdit);
    
    return (
        <div>
            {Array.isArray(tasks) && tasks.length !== 0 ? (
                tasks.map((task, index) => (
                    <Task key={index} task={task} id={index} />
                ))
            ) : (
                <h1>No Tasks Found</h1>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default AllTask;

taskReducer.js file:

It seems that the task.map in case "EDIT_TASK": is the root of the error. case "MARK_DONE": has the same structure but successfully works.

function taskReducer(tasks = [], action) {
    console.log("taskreducer");
    switch (action.type) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-lone-blocks
        case "ADD_TASK": {
            return [
                ...tasks,
                {
                    _id: action._id,
                    title: action.title,
                    description: action.description,
                    completed: false
                }
            ]
        }
        case "SET_TASK": {
            return action.payload
        }
        case "REMOVE_TASK": {
            console.log("Tasks before removal:", tasks);
            const updatedTasks = tasks.filter((task) => task._id !== action._id);
            console.log("Tasks after removal:", updatedTasks);
            return updatedTasks;
        }
        case "MARK_DONE": {
            return tasks.map((task) => {
                if (task._id === action._id) {
                    return {
                        ...task,
                        completed: !task.completed
                    }
                }
                return task
            })
        }
        case "EDIT_TASK": {
            return tasks.map((task) => {
                if (task._id === action._id) {
                    return {
                        ...task,
                        title: action.title,
                        description: action.description
                    };
                }
                return task;
            });
        }
        case 'SET_EDIT_MODE': {
            console.log('Processing SET_EDIT_MODE:', action.payload);
            return {
                ...tasks,
                taskToEdit: action.payload, // Set the task for editing
                editMode: true // Set edit mode to true
            };
        }
        case "CLEAR_EDIT_MODE": {
            console.log('Processing CLEAR_EDIT_MODE');
            return {
                ...tasks,
                taskToEdit: null,
                editMode: false
            };
        }
        default: {
            throw Error("Unknown Action" + action.type)
        }
    }
}

export default taskReducer;

In my server folder, taskController.js file:
import taskModel from "../models/taskModel.js";
import userModel from "../models/userModel.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
dotenv.config();

const addTask = async (req, res) => {
    const { _id, title, description } = req.body;
    const userId = req.user.id;

    const user = await userModel.find({_id: userId});
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
    }

    const taskId = _id ? mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id) : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

    console.log("Task to be saved:", { taskId, title, description, completed: false, userId });

    const newTask = new taskModel({ _id: taskId, title, description, completed: false, userId })

    newTask.save()
        .then((savedTask) => {
            return (res.status(200).json({ message: "Task added successfully", task: savedTask }))
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return (
                res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
            )
        }
        )
}

const removeTask = (req, res) => {
    const { _id } = req.query;

    console.log("Task ID to remove:", _id); // Log the ID being used for deletion

    taskModel.findByIdAndDelete( _id )
        .then((deletedTask) => {
            if (!deletedTask) {
                return res.status(404).json({ message: "Task not found" });
            }
            console.log("Deleted task:", deletedTask); // Log the deleted task
            return res.status(200).json({ message: "Task deleted successfully" });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error deleting task:", error); // Log any errors
            return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
        });
}

const getTask = (req, res) => {
    taskModel.find({ userId: req.user.id })
        .lean() // Convert Mongoose documents to plain JavaScript objects
        .then((data) => res.status(200).json(data))
        .catch((error) => res.status(501).json({ message: error.message }))
}


const updateTaskStatus = async (req, res) => {
    const { _id, completed } = req.body;

    try {
        // Find the task by _id and update the completed field
        const updatedTask = await taskModel.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, { completed }, { new: true });

        if (!updatedTask) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Task not found' });
        }

        res.json(updatedTask); // Return the updated task
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating task completion:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to update task completion status' });
    }
};


const editTask = async (req, res) => {
    const _id = req.params._id;
    const { title, description } = req.body;

    try {
        const updatedTask = await taskModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
            _id,
            { title, description },
            { new: true }
        );

        if (!updatedTask) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: "Task not found" });
        }

        return res.status(200).json({ message: "Task edited successfully", task: updatedTask });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error updating task:", error);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
    }
};


export { addTask, getTask, removeTask, updateTaskStatus, editTask }

This is what I encounter on my browser console when I save an edited task (task gets successfully edited and saved to the database):
XHR OPTIONS http://localhost:8000/api/task/editTask/663502dc2799787a594e2d6e [HTTP/1.1 204 No Content 3ms]

XHR POST http://localhost:8000/api/task/editTask/663502dc2799787a594e2d6e [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 221ms]

Task edited: Object { message: "Task edited successfully", task: {…} } SaveTask.jsx:37

taskreducer taskReducer.js:2

Uncaught TypeError: tasks.map is not a function
    taskReducer taskReducer.js:37
    React 3
    App App.js:19
    React 11
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:266
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:533
    js scheduler.development.js:571
    js scheduler.development.js:633
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 24


Could you add a log to the line where the error occurs and check what is the tasks value? It's probably an object instead of an array

@onur-doğan Sure. That's what returned: Tasks before mapping:  Object { 0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}, taskToEdit: {…}, editMode: true }

@onur-doğan Thank you. I was assuming that it is not an array but was not sure about how to handle it. I fixed it now. I'll share my answer here.

I was planning to mention that the issue is probably related to both of the SET_EDIT_MODE and CLEAR_EDIT_MODE dispatchers since they set the state as an object instead of an array but you already fixed it. Perfect then, you're welcome!

@onur-doğan Sorry for bothering you again. Would it be possible for you to check my question here which is related to the same app and share your opinion with me? Thank you.

No problem, sure. I think the problem is in in both of the SET_EDIT_MODE and CLEAR_EDIT_MODE dispatchers since in these parts the ...tasks code line converts the tasks array to an object. It probably breaks all other functionalities since the tasks should be an array. So, the taskToEdit and editMode fields should be in each array element as true/false instead of as an object. When you want to edit one of them, set these fields as true otherwise use them as false. E.G. I think you can set taskToEdit: true to the editable element in the tasks array for SET_EDIT_MODE

Hope, it's clear and helpful. Otherwise, let me know please, I can try to be more helpful

@onur-doğan I hope I'm not completely misunderstanding it but do you suggest me to add taskToEdit = boolean and editMode = boolean to every dispatcher in taskReducer? I've also tried a different approach such as changing the code in EDIT_TASK, SET_EDIT_MODE and CLEAR_EDIT_MODE considering ...tasks is an array but that broke the functionality as well.

Yes, I was suggesting you something like this. Because, we can't store taskToEdit or editMode in an array. Actually, there's a problem on the reducers generally. On the some of them, you set only tasks array to the context. For the others, you set all these fields as an object. I think, all of them should be an object and should include { tasks, editMode, taskToEdit fields. For example, for SET_EDIT_MODE, it can update state like { tasks, taskToEdit: action.payload, editMode: true}. As I understand the other components as well, the context should include these three

When you used spread syntax to set tasks to the context like ...tasks, it sets the tasks as an object so you shouldn't use ... there. That would fix some issues. But in the other part, for example in MARK_DONE dispatcher, it should return like return { tasks: tasks.map(...), ... } since when you return a mapped array, it still sets the context state as an array but it should be an object. So, I think you can check all these dispatchers and make sure all of them update states as an object. So, need to fix that complication, state should have set as one type (object) for each dispatcher

@onur-doğan Thanks for the help. I fixed the problem. Not as you have suggested but I converted the array in AllTask.jsx into an object and it solved Tasks getting disappeared. It might not be the best approach, anyway all four CRUD operations flawlessly work right now.

Perfect to hear that, you're welcome

Thank you user @onur-doğan for leading me to the solution.
I checked tasks value with a console.log statement which returned as Tasks before mapping:  Object { 0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}, taskToEdit: {…}, editMode: true }
Then I edited case "EDIT_TASK": in taskReducer.js to adjust how to access and update tasks as an object:
        case "EDIT_TASK": {
            const { taskToEdit, title, description } = action;
        
            if (tasks && tasks.taskToEdit) {
                const updatedTask = {
                    ...tasks.taskToEdit,
                    title,
                    description
                };
        
                return {
                    ...tasks,
                    taskToEdit: {
                        ...tasks.taskToEdit,
                        title,
                        description
                    },
                    [taskToEdit]: updatedTask
                };
            }
        
            return tasks;
        }

Now "editing and saving a task" works as expected, as seen on my browser console:
XHR OPTIONS http://localhost:8000/api/task/editTask/663502dc2799787a594e2d6e [HTTP/1.1 204 No Content 3ms]

XHR POST http://localhost:8000/api/task/editTask/663502dc2799787a594e2d6e [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 205ms]

Task edited: Object { message: "Task edited successfully", task: {…} } SaveTask.jsx:37

taskreducer taskReducer.js:2

Processing CLEAR_EDIT_MODE taskReducer.js:70

